# Installing matplotlib on mac book pro

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have downloaded matplotlib using the `pip3 install` command on to my Mac Book Pro.

I tried to run the following code

```
import numpy as np


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
plt.plot(t, s)
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('voltage (mV)')
plt.title('About as simple as it gets, folks')
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

I get this error

```
runfile('/Users/giridhar/PycharmProjects/numpy/matpotlib1.py', wdir='/Users/giridhar/PycharmProjects/numpy')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 11, in execfile
    stream = tokenize.open(file)  # @UndefinedVariable
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tokenize.py", line 392, in open
    buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/giridhar/PycharmProjects/numpy/matpotlib1.py'
```

Can you please let me know what is the mistake I am making?

Comment: Do you have python 3.5 or 3.6 installed?

Comment: How are you running the code? Is your script file called `matpotlib1.py`?

Comment: Yes, name of the script is matpotlib1.py. But I have the same issue with any other name as well.

Comment: Python 2.7.16 is the version number. Would my code not work for this version? Also the script file name is matpotlib1 that I ran which gave the error. BUT the same error occurs with any other script that has matplotlib code.

Comment: I did install 3.8 of Python and can see Python 3.8 library in Applications on my mac book. Yet, Python -V command gives the number 2.7 instead of 3.8 - not sure why? Can you please let me know what command should I use at Terminal to get correct version?.